# Download CSV directly into Python CSV parser

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I'm trying to download CSV content from morningstar and then parse its contents. If I inject the HTTP content directly into Python's CSV parser, the result is not formatted correctly. Yet, if I save the HTTP content to a file (/tmp/tmp.csv), and then import the file in the python's csv parser the result is correct. In other words, why does:

```
def finDownload(code,report):
    h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
    url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=' + code + '&region=AUS&culture=en_us&reportType='+ report + '&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&rounding=1&view=raw&productCode=usa&denominatorView=raw&number=1'
    headers, data = h.request(url)
    return data

balancesheet = csv.reader(finDownload('FGE','is'))
for row in balancesheet:
    print row
```

return:

```
['F']
['o']
['r']
['g']
['e']
[' ']
['G']
['r']
['o']
['u']
     (etc...)
```

instead of:

```
[Forge Group Limited (FGE) Income Statement']
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem results from the fact that iteration over a file is done line-by-line whereas iteration over a string is done character-by-character.

You want [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio)/[`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio#module-cStringIO) (Python 2) or [`io.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO) (Python 3, thanks to John Machin for pointing me to it) so a string can be treated as a file-like object:

**Python 2:**

```
mystring = 'a,"b\nb",c\n1,2,3'
import cStringIO
csvio = cStringIO.StringIO(mystring)
mycsv = csv.reader(csvio)
```

**Python 3**:

```
mystring = 'a,"b\nb",c\n1,2,3'
import io
csvio = io.StringIO(mystring, newline="")
mycsv = csv.reader(csvio)
```

Both will correctly preserve newlines inside quoted fields:

```
>>> for row in mycsv: print(row)
...
['a', 'b\nb', 'c']
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Is `splitlines` also gone from Python 3? I have always liked it better than `split('\n')`, as I suffer from backslashaphobia.

Comment: -3 `csvstring` is a rotten name for a list. Usually CSV files have CR LF as line separator; don't use `mystring.split('\n')`, use `mystring.splitlines()`. `StringIO` is not "gone", it has relocated to the `io` module and been renamed `BytesIO`. There is also a `StringIO` that works on py3k `str` objects. See http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html#module-io

Comment: @JohnMachin: Thanks for your comment. I have by now rewritten my answer a few times, so I hope it now stands up under close scrutiny :)

Comment: @Tim: You're almost there. With py2, use `cStringIO.StringIO`. The OP's data has neither `'` nor `"` in it. The default (and almost universally used) `quotechar` is `"`. As you wish to display correct behaviour with quoted embedded LFs, it would be better if you lost the `'` quotechar. Your py3 example starts unrealistically with a `str` object. The Python-supplied `urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()` produces `bytes`. Note that the payload starts with a UTF-8 "BOM" (for both py2 and py3, of course), and all of the remaining bytes are all ASCII. HTH :)