# php - download a csv file directly to the memory, preferably without cURL

Tags: php, parsing, curl, csv

This is equivalent of question: [Download CSV directly into Python CSV parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625079/download-csv-directly-into-python-csv-parser) but in php. Basically I'm looking for a library offering interface capable of doing things I do with python just in a few lines of code:

```
h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=' + code + '&region=AUS&culture=en_us&reportType='+ report + '&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&rounding=1&view=raw&productCode=usa&denominatorView=raw&number=1'
headers, data = h.request(url)
return data
```

I need to download and parse csv file but I would like to avoid using cURL and its low level interface. Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you expecxt to download it,with hopes and dreams?

Comment: I suposed you could use [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)...

Comment: with some library using which I don't have to do all this stuff like init, curl_setopt, bla bla. Just a three lines of easy to read code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite 3 lines:

```
function getURL($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ret;
}
```

Or I guess you could use file_get_contents, if you REALLY don't like cURL...

```
file_get_contents($url);
```

Also, take a look at [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for converting the strings from the above functions into an array with data from the CSV file.

Answer (score 4):

You can load a file into a variable with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. You can parse the result with [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
$data = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('http://example.com/data/my.csv'));
```

If you need to set specific headers or use an other delimeters see the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

[fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) should be enabled